# Google Workspace Add-ons Quickstart Cats stopped working on iOS gmail

Tags: google-workspace-add-ons

I've started to receive reports that the add-on we have been using for a while stopped working on iOS mobile. I was able to confirm this and started to dig into the issues. I've been able to reproduce the error with the "Quickstart: Cats Google Workspace Add-on" using multiple google accounts (gmail and workspace). It appears that cards, navigation, and notifications being returned from a function called by a button in card do not render on iOS Gmail. The code appears to work on desktop. I was able to demo this with the Quickstart tutorial. I removed the need for whitelist urls on mobile using the following createCatCard that shows the current time instead of a cat picture. This project works on desktop but not on iOS Gmail.

I've reported this to google via their issue tracker (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/210484310) but they state that "The Issue Tracker is intended for reporting issues and asking for features related to development with/on Google products, therefore it is not the best place to ask for support on this matter."

Does anyone know if iOS Gmail add-ons are still supported and if there is a workaround for this behavior?

```
/**
 * Creates a card with an image of a cat, overlayed with the text.
 * @param {String} text The text to overlay on the image.
 * @param {Boolean} isHomepage True if the card created here is a homepage;
 *      false otherwise. Defaults to false.
 * @return {CardService.Card} The assembled card.
 */
function createCatCard(text, isHomepage) {
  // Explicitly set the value of isHomepage as false if null or undefined.
  if (!isHomepage) {
    isHomepage = false;
  }

  // Use the "Cat as a service" API to get the cat image. Add a "time" URL
  // parameter to act as a cache buster.
  var now = new Date();
  // Replace formward slashes in the text, as they break the CataaS API.
  var caption = text.replace(/\//g, ' ');
  var d = new Date();
  var textLabel = CardService.newTextParagraph().setText("Current Time." + d.toLocaleTimeString());

  // Create a button that changes the cat image when pressed.
  // Note: Action parameter keys and values must be strings.
  var action = CardService.newAction()
      .setFunctionName('onChangeCat')
      .setParameters({text: text, isHomepage: isHomepage.toString()});
  var button = CardService.newTextButton()
      .setText('Change cat')
      .setOnClickAction(action)
      .setTextButtonStyle(CardService.TextButtonStyle.FILLED);
  var buttonSet = CardService.newButtonSet()
      .addButton(button);


  // Assemble the widgets and return the card.
  var section = CardService.newCardSection()
      .addWidget(textLabel)
      .addWidget(buttonSet);
  var card = CardService.newCardBuilder()
      .addSection(section);

  if (!isHomepage) {
    // Create the header shown when the card is minimized,
    // but only when this card is a contextual card. Peek headers
    // are never used by non-contexual cards like homepages.
    var peekHeader = CardService.newCardHeader()
      .setTitle('Contextual Cat')
      .setImageUrl('https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system/1x/pets_black_48dp.png')
      .setSubtitle(text);
    card.setPeekCardHeader(peekHeader)
  }

  return card.build();
}
```

Comment: Looks like the issue tracker issue has been reopened and it is currently being investigated. Are you observing this behavior solely on the Gmail iOS App?

Comment: I don't have access to an android device for testing, but I'm not seeing this behavior on desktop.

Comment: It seems that the issue has been reopened on Google's Issue Tracker, so I would assume that the issue is under investigation now.

Comment: It looks like the issue was either with server-side or iOS Gmail App and appears to have been resolved.